# How to read a simple xpm image and display it using Java?

Tags: java, image

I am assigned a task to build a simple xpm image viewer. I can't use any existing toolkit library for this. 
I know that xpm images are string array like this ( I can write one) -

```
/* XPM */
static const char *const hi[] = {
"7 5 2 1",
"  c black",
". c yellow",

"..   ..",
". . . .",
".  .  .",
".     .",
".     ."
};
```

I want to use java for this. My question is -
1. How to make a String variable (hi[]) from this xpm file so that I can use it in my main class?
2. Good way to display it in a GUI?
3. Any other dictation...

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Looks like C/C++ code, or am I completely off.

Comment: Please tell me in C/C++? I will try to deduce something from it..

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I meant.  This file format is nothing but an array of String in the C programming language which suggests that you may wish to do your coding in C (a language which I have dim recollection of having used many years ago).

Comment: @Hovercraft: The format resembles a C string array so it can be easily included in C source files, but actually the file format is precisely defined and can also be used by programs who are not C compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to firstly write a parser - a program/method/class/whatever that reads this file line-wise and extract the necessary data.

```
BufferedReader r =
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file),
                                             "US-ASCII"));
```

gives you a BufferedReader, which has a readLine() method.
The first some lines you throw away or handle specially, and then the main bunch of lines are the real image data. There you throw away the quotes and commas, and have the plain data in string form.

To put it in a image, look at the classes in java.awt.image - specially BufferedImage and the classes used by it (Raster/WriteableRaster, IndexColorModel).

Instead, you could also simply hold the data in your String[] form, and in the paint-method of a custom component access the individual pixels. This would be a bit slower, I think.

Comment: Okay, but it would be much easier if I could count this as a variable

Comment: The format of the File is such that it is valid C code, so it could be simply included in C programs (this is the purpose of the format).
You can't do this in Java (and you still would need a Java compiler), so this is off ... you need to parse it.
After my first step you have the data as a String[] (if you do it right), so you can have a variable with it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this will work for you: http://www.bolthole.com/java/Xpm.html , but I reckon once it is converted into a Java image, you should able to do whatever you want in Java.

Comment: I can't use any existing toolkit library for this :(. Though thanks for the link.